# Hide navbar on scroll down and show image to open it back

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, show-hide

I'm trying to make a navbar which will hide on scroll down and will be replaced with a button which should return back the navbar when clicked.

You can exactly what I need here: [example](http://eu.battle.net/overwatch/en/game/).

Here is a sample of the code that I'm trying to use but, I need when the navbar is hidden to show a link or a picture in the top center of the browser, which is clickable and when I click it to show the navbar again. And also to stop the showing when scroll up.

```js
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
   background:url(
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: Rather than an external link that may change or break, would you add a description into the question? If you can also show what you have found or tried in relation to that thing, you'll find people are more likely to dig into the problem with you.

Comment: Hello Halfer, 

Unfortunately I didn't find anything even close to the example I attached in the post. I found a lot of scripts to hide and show the navbar on close, but nothing that would visualize a button after the navbar is hidden. Anyway I will add a script to the post and will try to explain better the problem. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: So why not using the picture you want, and give it `position: fixed; top: -100px;` or something like that. When a user scrolls down it will scroll this picture down by setting `top: 0;` using javascript

Comment: JiFus that's an idea or at least an alternative option. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score -1):

I'm looking to do something similar.  Re-appear on scroll up versus button click.  Regardless, this javascript (not mine) should do the trick:

https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/

Here's what I ended up with in React:

```
ListLayout = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {

        return {
            didScroll: false,
            lastScrollTop: 0,
            delta: 5,
            navbarHeight: 0
        }
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        // because our window is our scrollable container we need to add an event listener
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    },

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // because react isnt managing the event we need to remove it when the component unmounts
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            navbarHeight : $('nav').outerHeight()
        });
    },

    handleScroll (event) {
        this.setState({
            didScroll : true
        });
    },

    render() {

        setInterval(function() {
            if (this.state.didScroll) {
                this.hasScrolled();
                this.setState({
                    didScroll : false
                });
            }
        }.bind(this), 250);

        return (
          <div className="container-fluid">
              <NavBar />
              {this.props.container}
          </div>
        )
    },

    hasScrolled() {

        var st = $(window).scrollTop();

        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if( Math.abs ( this.state.lastScrollTop - st ) <= this.state.delta)
            return;

        // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
        // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > this.state.lastScrollTop && st > this.state.navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            $('.search-bar-css').addClass('navbar-hidex2');
            $('nav').addClass('navbar-hide');
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $('.search-bar-css').removeClass('navbar-hidex2').addClass('navbar-showx2');
                $('nav').removeClass('navbar-hide').addClass('navbar-show');
            }
        }

        this.setState({
            lastScrollTop : st
        });

    }

});
```